# How can I change background icone svg path

Tags: android, svg

How can I change the icone svg background, I'm working with Android Studio and the `"android: fillColor =" # 9E9E9E ""` attribute does not change the background.

I needed the background to be gray

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="32dp"
    android:viewportHeight="32.0"
    android:viewportWidth="32.0"
    android:fillColor="#9E9E9E"
    android:width="32dp">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#9E9E9E"
        android:pathData="M28.86 17.342l-3.64-6.402c-.292-.433-.712-.729-1.163-.8a1.124 1.124 0 0 0-.889.213c-.63.488-.742 1.181-.33 2.061l1.222 2.587 1.4 2.46c2.234 4.085 1.511 8.007-2.145 11.663-.26.26-.526.49-.797.707 1.42-.084 2.881-.683 4.292-2.094 3.822-3.823 3.565-7.876 2.05-10.395zm-6.252 11.075c3.352-3.35 3.998-6.775 1.978-10.469l-3.378-5.945c-.292-.432-.712-.728-1.163-.8a1.122 1.122 0 0 0-.89.213c-.63.49-.742 1.182-.33 2.061l1.72 3.638a.502.502 0 0 1-.806.568l-8.91-8.91a1.335 1.335 0 0 0-1.887 1.886l5.292 5.292a.5.5 0 0 1-.707.707l-5.292-5.292-1.492-1.492c-.503-.503-1.382-.505-1.887 0a1.337 1.337 0 0 0 0 1.886l1.493 1.492 5.292 5.292a.499.499 0 0 1-.353.854.5.5 0 0 1-.354-.147L5.642 13.96a1.338 1.338 0 0 0-1.887 0 1.338 1.338 0 0 0 0 1.887l2.23 2.228 3.322 3.324a.499.499 0 0 1-.353.853.502.502 0 0 1-.354-.146l-3.323-3.324a1.333 1.333 0 0 0-1.886 0 1.325 1.325 0 0 0-.39.943c0 .356.138.691.39.943l6.396 6.397c3.528 3.53 8.86 5.313 12.821 1.353zM12.73 9.26l5.68 5.68-.49-1.037c-.518-1.107-.426-2.13.224-2.89l-3.303-3.304a1.337 1.337 0 0 0-1.886 0 1.326 1.326 0 0 0-.39.944c0 .217.067.42.165.607zm14.787 19.184c-1.599 1.6-3.417 2.392-5.353 2.392-.349 0-.7-.03-1.058-.082a7.922 7.922 0 0 1-3.667.887c-3.049 0-6.115-1.626-8.359-3.87l-6.396-6.397A2.315 2.315 0 0 1 2 19.724a2.327 2.327 0 0 1 1.923-2.296l-.875-.875a2.339 2.339 0 0 1 0-3.3 2.33 2.33 0 0 1 1.24-.647l-.139-.139c-.91-.91-.91-2.39 0-3.3.884-.884 2.421-.882 3.301 0l.138.14a2.335 2.335 0 0 1 3.948-1.24l.093.092c.091-.423.291-.828.62-1.157a2.336 2.336 0 0 1 3.3 0l3.384 3.386a2.167 2.167 0 0 1 1.271-.173c.534.086 1.03.354 1.441.765.11-.549.415-1.034.911-1.418a2.12 2.12 0 0 1 1.661-.41c.727.117 1.385.565 1.853 1.262l3.652 6.423c1.704 2.832 2.025 7.377-2.205 11.607zM13.217.484l-1.917.882 2.37 2.837-.454-3.719zm8.487.877l-1.928-.86-.44 3.697 2.368-2.837zM16.5 3.293L15.478-.005h2.044L16.5 3.293z"/>
</vector>
```

My SVG Path 
https://jsfiddle.net/dq9f0ane/

The "clap" has to turn gray as in the 2 pictures next

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZsTM.png)Try to Change the path data like this:

```
android:pathData="M28.86 17.342l-3.64-6.402c-.292-.433-.712-.729-1.163-.8a1.124 1.124 0 0 0-.889.213c-.63.488-.742 1.181-.33 2.061l1.222 2.587 1.4 2.46c2.234 4.085 1.511 8.007-2.145 11.663-.26.26-.526.49-.797.707 1.42-.084 2.881-.683 4.292-2.094 3.822-3.823 3.565-7.876 2.05-10.395zm-6.252 11.075c3.352-3.35 3.998-6.775 1.978-10.469l-3.378-5.945c-.292-.432-.712-.728-1.163-.8a1.122 1.122 0 0 0-.89.213c-.63.49-.742 1.182-.33 2.061l1.72 3.638a.502.502 0 0 1-.806.568l-8.91-8.91a1.335 1.335 0 0 0-1.887 1.886l5.292 5.292a.5.5 0 0 1-.707.707l-5.292-5.292-1.492-1.492c-.503-.503-1.382-.505-1.887 0a1.337 1.337 0 0 0 0 1.886l1.493 1.492 5.292 5.292a.499.499 0 0 1-.353.854.5.5 0 0 1-.354-.147L5.642 13.96a1.338 1.338 0 0 0-1.887 0 1.338 1.338 0 0 0 0 1.887l2.23 2.228 3.322 3.324a.499.499 0 0 1-.353.853.502.502 0 0 1-.354-.146l-3.323-3.324a1.333 1.333 0 0 0-1.886 0 1.325 1.325 0 0 0-.39.943c0 .356.138.691.39.943l6.396 6.397c3.528 3.53 8.86 5.313 12.821 1.353zM12.73 9.26l5.68 5.68-.49-1.037c-.518-1.107-.426-2.13.224-2.89l-3.303-3.304a1.337 1.337 0 0 0-1.886 0 1.326 1.326 0 0 0-.39.944c0 .217.067.42.165.607zM13.217.484l-1.917.882 2.37 2.837-.454-3.719zm8.487.877l-1.928-.86-.44 3.697 2.368-2.837zM16.5 3.293L15.478-.005h2.044L16.5 3.293z"/>
```

Comment: Perfect! As you did? which tools did you use?

Comment: I didn't use any tool I just removed some unwanted data in path data. Compare both the path data you will understand.